# End of file expected .jsonc [Ln 1, Col 23]

Tags: emoji

I am trying to install :emojisense: in Visual Studio Code. After I install the program, I get an error saying:

> End of file expected .jsonc [Ln 1, Col 23]

This is the code:

```javascript
"emojisense.languages": {    "plaintext": {
        "markupCompletionsEnabled": true,
        "emojiDecoratorsEnabled": true
    },
    "javascript.validate.enable": false,
    "abap": true,
    "bat": true,
    "bibtex": true,
    "clojure": true,
    "coffeescript": true,
    "c": true,
    "cpp": true,
    "csharp": true,
    "css": true,
    "diff": true,
    "dockerfile": true,
    "fsharp": true,
    "git-commit": true,
    "git-rebase": true,
    "go": true,
    "groovy": true,
    "handlebars": true,
    "html": true,
    "ini": true,
    "java": true,
    "javascript": true,
    "javascriptreact": true,
    "json": true,
    "jsonc": true,
    "latex": true,
    "less": true,
    "lua": true,
    "makefile": true,
    "markdown": true,
    "objective-c": true,
    "objective-cpp": true,
    "perl6": true,
    "php": true,
    "powershell": true,
    "jade": true,
    "python": true,
    "r": true,
    "razor": true,
    "ruby": true,
    "rust": true,
    "scss": true,
    "sass": true,
    "shaderlab": true,
    "shellscript": true,
    "sql": true,
    "swift": true,
    "typescript": true,
    "typescriptreact": true,
    "tex": true,
    "vb": true,
    "xml": true,
    "xsl": true,
    "yaml": true
}
```

I am trying to write suggested emojis in Visual Studio Code using ":".

Answer (score 0):

You are missing opening and closing curly braces `{` at the start, and `}` at the end, so the JSON content should be:

```
{
   "emojisense.languages":{
      "plaintext":{
         "markupCompletionsEnabled":true,
         "emojiDecoratorsEnabled":true
      },
      "javascript.validate.enable":false,
      "abap":true,
      "bat":true,
      "bibtex":true,
      "clojure":true,
      "coffeescript":true,
      "c":true,
      "cpp":true,
      "csharp":true,
      "css":true,
      "diff":true,
      "dockerfile":true,
      "fsharp":true,
      "git-commit":true,
      "git-rebase":true,
      "go":true,
      "groovy":true,
      "handlebars":true,
      "html":true,
      "ini":true,
      "java":true,
      "javascript":true,
      "javascriptreact":true,
      "json":true,
      "jsonc":true,
      "latex":true,
      "less":true,
      "lua":true,
      "makefile":true,
      "markdown":true,
      "objective-c":true,
      "objective-cpp":true,
      "perl6":true,
      "php":true,
      "powershell":true,
      "jade":true,
      "python":true,
      "r":true,
      "razor":true,
      "ruby":true,
      "rust":true,
      "scss":true,
      "sass":true,
      "shaderlab":true,
      "shellscript":true,
      "sql":true,
      "swift":true,
      "typescript":true,
      "typescriptreact":true,
      "tex":true,
      "vb":true,
      "xml":true,
      "xsl":true,
      "yaml":true
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved: I didn’t start with `{}`.

Comment: What do you mean by *"start"*? [Enclose](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/enclose#Verb)?